# Dataset for Big Data Project - Social Network Analysis in Telecommunications

Tags: dataset, social-networking, telecommunication, bigdata

I want to do a Social Network Analysis using Hadoop in Telecom industry. I'm looking for a dataset to work... There anyone knows a good dataset to analyze some relationships between users?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links for social network analytics dataset.

[Provided by Arizona State University](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/pages/datasets)

[UCINET IV](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/ucinet/ucidata.htm#kazalo)

[Provide by Stanford University](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/#socnets)

Comment: Many thanks anshul_cached. You don't a dataset specific for telecommunications? I can't found it :(

Comment: Let me know if this could help https://bigml.com/user/francisco/gallery/dataset/5163ad540c0b5e5b22000383s

Comment: Can't acess to it :(